# Defer execution of <Script> tag until after jQuery .load completes

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to 'include' some generated HTML code on my page with jQuery load (injecting it into #loadhead div):

```
<script>
    $("#loadhead").load("head.php");
</script>

<script defer>
    ... rest of the code
</script>
```

I want the second part of the script to load only after head.php is done loading. I tried to enforce execution of the second script tag with defer, but it deson't seem to work - still, once in a while, head.php doesn't manage to load before the rest of the code. What can I do to ensure it is always loaded completely? It generates some JavaScript values that are used by the 'defer' script.

Comment: `$("#loadhead").load("head.php",function(){ loadrest() });` or `$("#loadhead").load("head.php",loadrest);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options for you:

### 1. Use a function you call from `load`'s callback

Put your second script's code in a function, so it's *loaded* but not *run*, and then call that function from `load`'s success callback.

Example:

```
<script>
$("#loadhead").load("head.php", otherStuff);
function otherStuff() {
    // ...
}
</script>
```

(I didn't see any reason they should be in separate `script` tags, so they aren't.)

I'd probably put that all in a `.js` file and link it rather than having script embedded in the HTML inline.

### 2. Load the script when `load` is done

Don't include the second `script` tag at all; load the script later in the `load` success callback, either using `$.getScript` or appending a `script` element.

Example:

```
<script>
$("#loadhead").load("head.php", function() {
    $.getScript("otherstuff.js");
});
</script>
```

(I didn't see any reason they should be in separate `script` tags, so they aren't.)

---

I'd very much go with Option #1, to avoid unnecessary delays.